# Character won't stay in boundary when page gets zoomed

Tags: javascript, css, border, zooming

So I have the classic set-up where

```
if (position >= BLA) {
    // make it so character doesn't move
}
```

However the problem with this approach I found is when I set `BLA` to equal my worlds boundary in a game (i.e. 1500px), it will work fine however when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in, it messes up and the edges of the character image go outside the boundary. I know I have seen some games where even when you zoom in on the page, the game window doesn't change size. How could I implement that in either JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: in your css try setting div to `width :100%` and `overflow: auto`

Comment: That didn't really work, I am setting the requirement to be when the position reaches a certain pixel value -> stop moving. Do you think there is a way to set the position equal to the CSS border value? that way it will stop at the border no matter how the pixels get scaled?